# Is it ethical, just to ask questions and not answer (as a amateur)?

Tags: discussion

As a amateur in almost all fields, I ask some silly and many questions. And as an amateur I don't think I should answer questions I have no deep knowledge about. But at the same time it doesn't seem right either?

Comment: Sure.  Just don't be like this guy http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman (2,027 questions, 14 answers)